# How to configure a pure C project in QT Creator?

Tags: clang, qt-creator

In QT Creator 4.0.1, how to configure a non-QT project (i.e. with project.config, project.files, project.includes) to analyze code with only C (and not C++) in mind.

For example, in C this warning should not appear.
[image: print screen of qt creator]

I guess there is something to configure in the clang code model but I can't figure it out where.

Comment: What is "clang code"? I somehow dout this is the `main` of clang.

Comment: It's not "clang code" it's "clang code model".
Please learn more about "clang code model" [here](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-clang-codemodel.html#using-clang-code-model)

Comment: No need, I don't use that IDE. Itr still is not related to clang nor C.

Comment: Maybe not to C but definitely related to clang. Learn more about clang integration with IDE [here](http://clang.llvm.org/features.html#ideintegration)